# I want to use Google Translate as part of some C code

Tags: c, google-translate

I want to use [Google Translate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) as part of a C code I am writing. I understand that Google Translate is used with JavaScript. How do I get it work as part of my C code?

How do I make a connection from my C code to the Google site?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Google Translate API](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=google+translate+api&aq=3&aqi=n1g10&aql=&oq=google+translate+) with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: can you tell me what curl is?

Comment: curl is a library for transferring data using various protocols ..more information here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#fonje is a better link for the API.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you're not violating their [terms of service.](http://translate.google.com/toolkit/TOS.html) Just because it's freely available on the web doesn't mean it's freely available to embed into applications.

Then look into a library that lets you "simulate" web interactions from C, such as [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).